# how to output value without brackets in spark?

Tags: java, scala, shell, apache-spark

I want to store the dataframe as pure value, but what I got is value with brackets, the code:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load(filename)
//I skip the processes here, just shows as an example
df.rdd.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```

The data is:

```
[40fc4ab12a174bf4]
[5572a277df472931]
[5fbce7c5c854996b]
[b4283abd92ea904]
[2f486994064f6875]
```

What I want is :

```
40fc4ab12a174bf4
5572a277df472931
5fbce7c5c854996b
b4283abd92ea904
2f486994064f6875
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `spark-csv` to write data:

```
df.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .save(outputPath)
```

Or using rdd, just get the first value from `Row`:

```
df.rdd.map(l => l.get(0)).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```